# use LLm hosted on sagemaker with LlamaIndex

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model, llama-index

I have a LLM model hosted on sagemaker endpoint. I have a code which with langchain to use the sagemaker endpoint hosted LLM.

```
from langchain.embeddings import SagemakerEndpointEmbeddings
content_handler = ContentHandler()
embeddings = SagemakerEndpointEmbeddings(
    # credentials_profile_name="credentials-profile-name",
    endpoint_name="paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2",
    region_name="me-central-1",
    content_handler=content_handler,
)
```

I need assistance in using LlamaIndex to deploy a pre-trained LLM model on Amazon SageMaker. Despite my research efforts, I couldn't find any useful information. Can someone provide me with a code snippet or guidance on how to achieve this?